# How to show what shard the guild is using in the custom status of my bot?

Tags: discord.js, sharding

So I am making a discord.js bot and I am trying to do sharding for my bot. Is there a way so that in the custom status of the bot it can show this?:

Watching Shard(the shard the guild is using)

is that possible? And if it is can you guys please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Guild.shardId`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=shardId).

```js
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    message.reply(`This guild is on Shard ${message.guild.shardId}.`);
});
```